# How to get state-space equations form from a block diagram?

Tags: laplace-transform, state-space

This is the block diagram that I'd like to transform into a state-space representation, where $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are inputs and $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ are the outputs of the system

[image]

I tried to place state variables on the diagram and go from there (is there a cleaner way to do this?):

[image]

$ x_{1} = y_{1} $

$ x_{2} = \dot{x}_{1} $

$ x_{3} = \dot{x}_{2} $

$ x_{4} = y_{2} $

$ x_{5} = \dot{x}_{4} $

$ x_{6} = \dot{x}_{5} $

I am not sure how to go about from here. The $\frac{1}{s+1}$ block is confusing me. I know I can write the output signal from the $\frac{1}{s+1}$ block like this:

$ out_{1} = u_{1} - o\dot{u}t_{1} $

$ out_{2} = u_{2} - o\dot{u}t_{2} $

But I don't see if that's even useful and if it is, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one odd diagram. And you are frankly in the right direction. Now you only need to express each state as the equation from before in the diagram.

[image: Diagram with states]

So lets start with $x_1$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_1 &= \frac{1}{s+1}u_1 & \rightarrow x_1 &= u_1-\dot{x}_1 \\
x_2 &= x_1 - u_1 + u_2 & \rightarrow x_2 &= u_2 - \dot{x}_1 \\
\dot{x}_3 &= x_2 \\
\dot{x}_4 &= x_3
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
And the other side:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
x_5 &= \frac{1}{s+1}u_2 &\rightarrow x_5 = u_2-\dot{x}_5 \\
x_6 &= x_5 + x_3 - x_7 \\
\dot{x}_7 &= x_6 \\ 
\dot{x}_8 &= x_7 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
And now substitute where ever needed to write everything as an equation of a state derivative:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}_1 &=u_1 - x_1 \\
\dot{x}_3 &= u_2 - u_1 - x_1 \\
\dot{x}_4 &= x_3 \\
\dot{x}_5 &= u_2-x_5 \\
\dot{x}_7 &= x_5 + x_3 - x_7 \\
\dot{x}_8 &= x_7 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
As there are 6 integrators, having 6 states does make sense. Despite that, I do think it can be simplified, but lets first implement it into a state space
$$\dot{x} = \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_7 \\ x_8\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 \\ 0&0 \\0&1\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u_1 \\ u_2\end{bmatrix}$$

From this getting the C matrix is pretty self-explanatory. If there are any more questions, I am happy to hear.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What if on the bottom row the 1/s+1 and 1/s after the summation are swapped?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/50087)

Answer (score 0):

This system can be represented by 6-number of state variables. We do not need 8 states. Apparently the states x_2 and x_6 are not needed.